# Does subscribing to an event add the handler function to the event or the event delegate's invocation list?

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates

I am trying to debunk how many tutorials on .NET Events and Delegates are using the Event and the Delegate (believe this is an invocation list?) interchangeably when describing an object subscribing to the event.

In the case of this example code, some I've listened to have said that handlerFunction is being added to the Event's invocation list, whilst others say it is being added to to the delegate (which is what I originally thought was the (only) invocation list.)

What is the breakdown of where the subscribers are actually subscribing to?

```cs
delegate void MyEventHandler (int x, string y);

class myClass {
    public event MyEventHandler MyEvent;
}

myClass obj = new myClass();
obj.MyEvent += handlerFunction;
```

Comment: According to Jeffrey Richter, delegates can be linked together to a linked list. Hence, the invocation list of an event is implemented as a linked list of delegates.

Comment: @KristofU. You have that backwards.  An event is backed by a single delegate.  A single delegate represents an invocation list of all of the methods that will be called when that delegate is invoked.  So a delegate has an invocation list, rather than an invocation list having a bunch of delegates.  (This is of course when discussing auto-implemented events; for a custom event you can back it however you want.)

Comment: @Servy How come some places show examples of obj.MyEvent += new myEventHandler(handlerFunction) when myEventHandler would be a delegate and that would be adding a delegate to a delegate?

Comment: @Servy You're right. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: @FelipeWarrener-Iglesias How can you add an integer to an integer variable?  The same logic applies.

Comment: @Servy I don't understand. An event is an instance of a delegate and we're adding delegates to the event. Does the event delegate contain a list of delegates? Delegates are for referencing methods not for holding a list of references I thought?

Comment: @FelipeWarrener-Iglesias An (auto implemented) event is a *wrapper* around a delegate, it isn't itself a delegate.  As I said in my earlier comment, a delegate contains a list of methods to invoke (not other delegates, just things to execute when it is invoked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining an event creates a variable with the delegate as the type. It refers to an instance of the delegate. So you could say that the event has an invocation list or that the instance of the delegate has an invocation list, because event = instance of delegate.

This is why if you declare an `event`, as you have:

```
public event MyEventHandler MyEvent;
```

`MyEvent` is a `Delegate`, and you can call its `GetInvocationList()` method. `GetInvocationList()` is a member of `Delegate`.

Comment: How does: this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load); work then?

In that example we're taking a delegate (load event) and adding another delegate to it pointing to the handler. Why are we adding a delegate to another delegate? If that's going in a list then how is that possible as delegates are pointers not lists? What's the actual explanation of this list?

Comment: `delegate` declares a variable of type `Delegate`. `Delegate` is a class, and an instance of that class is used as a pointer. But an instance of that class isn't *just* a pointer. It's an object with properties and methods, including an invocation list.

Answer (score 1):

Delegates are immutable, not mutable.  So technically when you subscribe an additional handler to an event you're not *adding* a handler to an existing delegate instance's invocation list, you're creating a new delegate whose invocation list will contain everything in the old delegate's invocation list plus your new handler, and assigning that new delegate to the backing store for that event.

All that said, I expect that what you're reading is just shortcutting a bit and not going into overly specific details here as it's not really a point relevant to what I expect they're actually trying to discuss at the moment.

As for the difference between thinking of it as "a delegate" versus, "an invocation list".  Every delegate *is* just an invocation list.  There isn't anything more to any delegates.  There really isn't anything particularly wrong with referring to either here.  Technically the event has a delegate, and subscribing the event handler is creating a new delegate that has a slightly different invocation list internally than the old delegate, and that new delegate is being assigned to the backing store.  Shortcutting that to saying that adding a handler is adding a new method to the invocation list is...at least getting across the important points there.  That the invocation list is held in a delegate instance isn't really particularly critical to understanding how to subscribe a handler to an event.

Comment: So they're being added to the delegate and there's no such invocation list on the event?

Comment: @FelipeWarrener-Iglesias An (auto-implemented) event is just a wrapper around a single delegate, allowing handlers to be added to it, removed from it, or for it to be invoked from within the class.  The *delegate* has an invocation list of all of the methods to execute when it's invoked.

Comment: Could you explain why some places show examples of obj.MyEvent += new myEventHandler(handlerFunction) when myEventHandler would be a delegate and that would be adding a delegate to a delegate?

Comment: @FelipeWarrener-Iglesias Because they're adding to delegates together, creating a new delegate that is the sum of the other two, just like you can add two integers together, creating a new one that's the sum of those two.  You add delegates by combining their invocation lists.